# Multiple Markers on Map with different icons and titles

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have updated my question please review it
Iam developing Blood Donar app in android.In that Iam using Google Map to display the donar on map.To show multiple markers on map I am trying this code but its crashing the application

```
public class Profiles {
String name;
String email;
String latitude;
String longitude;
int type;

public Profiles() { }

public Profiles(String name, String email, String latitude, String longitude , int type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

and in MapsActivity Iam getting it like

```
 private void fun() {
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.profiles).child("lRSFuI5pvBZh1VZQWHI4ev52gXF2");
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot parent : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Profiles profiles = parent.getValue(Profiles.class);
                            name = profiles.getName();
                            String email = profiles.getEmail();
                            lat = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLatitude());
                        lon = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLongitude());
                            type = profiles.getType();

                        }
        }

     @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            if (type == 1) {
                marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(name);
            } else {
                marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_bloodbank));
            }
            mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
            mMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
```

I get this error for this

[image]

If I get this all detail in any other activity it gives me everything wihtout crashing but when I try to use it in Maps Activity it crashes the app direct giving this error.I can understand why its crashing while Iam getting detail in other activities I have tried for testing and getting perfectly all in toast and logcat.

Comment: You can simply create different marker objects and add them to the app. You can customize each object's icon, position (LatLng) as well as title.

Comment: I have updated my question can you please review it again.

Comment: error literally denotes that the `double` value you are using for lat-long is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As per above code snippet, both are async process and you are trying to call it both together.

when you try to add marker you should check whether `isMapReady` or not also as per above crash `latlng` value are null, you should wait until data load from firebase method load callback.

So ideally it would be

```
private void fun() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.profiles).child("lRSFuI5pvBZh1VZQWHI4ev52gXF2");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot parent : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Profiles profiles = parent.getValue(Profiles.class);
                        name = profiles.getName();
                        String email = profiles.getEmail();
                        lat = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLatitude());
                    lon = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLongitude());
                        type = profiles.getType();

                //Add your marker code here with map ready check. 

                    }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question can you please review it again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not `mMap.animateCamera` and `mMap.moveCamera` inside the loop. After loop, you should set your camera location and zoom to any one place.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    LatLng latLngForMarker = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getLat()), Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getLng()));

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLngForMarker);
    markerOptions.title(arrayList.get(i).getUserName());
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(latLngForMarker).title(arrayList.get(i).getUserName()));
}

// Then you can set default zoom to any one location:
// default latitude and longitude for init and zoom camera, you can change by your requirement
double defaultLatitude = 23.0201818;
double defaultLongitude = 72.4396566;
CameraUpdate centerGujarat = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(defaultLatitude, defaultLongitude));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
mMap.moveCamera(centerGujarat);
mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: I have to show different image with each icon from drawables, by doing this isn't it only one picture for evey item (   markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon));)

Comment: You should check that inside loop and set different icons.( `markerOptions.icon` )

Comment: I have updated my question can you please review it again.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of effort I have find a way to solve this issue I still didn't understand how its worked because its was an issue of calling function properly and according to me I was doing fine but still with some minor amendments I got it
Firstly I have created a Array list of MarkerOptions and added marker data in it where Iam getting data from my firebase Database and in the same function I then added a For Loop in which I start adding my markers and then call this function in OnMapReady Function 
Like This :

```
private void gettingMarkersData() {

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.content).child(Constants.profiles);
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot parent : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Profiles profiles = parent.getValue(Profiles.class);
                        String name = profiles.getName();
                          latD = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLatitude());
                        lonD = Double.valueOf(profiles.getLongitude());
                        int type = profiles.getType();

                        if (type == 1) {
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latD, lonD)).title(name);
                            marker.add(markerOptions);
                        } else if(type == 2) {
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latD, lonD)).title(name)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_bloodbank));
                            marker.add(markerOptions);
                        }

                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < marker.size(); i++) {

                        mMap.addMarker(marker.get(i));
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And then in OnMapReady I call this function :

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);

        gettingMarkersData();
/* for (int i = 0; i < marker.size(); i++) {
                    mMap.addMarker(marker.get(i));
                }*/

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0F));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    }
```

Before doing this I was adding markers in OnMapReady (the for loop which I have commented ) for adding the markers and it was not adding markers then I paste it in gettingMarkersData(). and its start working fine.