# Not getting current location on maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to Android. I am using maps and trying to show current position in maps but don't know why it only showing blue screen. I have seen others question on this site but not find answer.

COde:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
        getMyLocation();
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0F));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happens sometime.Once I also got stuck in the same issue and on debugging got the issue.
just change this

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
        getMyLocation();
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0F));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

to this

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14.0F));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        getMyLocation();

}
```

try this out You are new to android I will suggest you try to debug problem using debugger and see where your are getting the issue and getting weird behavior In this either you can remove the zoomTo() method or if your are using it then zoom it before giving location

Comment: thanku man it worked
and  yes I will definetly work on your suggestion

Comment: #Umair If I want to show multiple markers on map by dynamically getting data from database,right  now Iam using Firebase Database ,how can I do that
can you please help me in that also

Comment: #ali I just answered this to my own question few hours back ,have a look to it and try that solution may it helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59387076/5816306

Comment: #umair I dont have point to comment on other post that's why commenting over here thanku man it worked like a charm. Though I have some minor issue but I already found solution using your suggestion of debugging .Once again thanku man